# symfony 4 get doctrine documentManger with dependency injection

Tags: mongodb, doctrine, symfony4

I have to use Symfony 4 and MongoDB in a project. I can reach the DocumentManager in the controller like this:

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
```

in runtime, but not like other services (for example Doctrine EntityManager) via any method's or constructor's argument. So I don't know how to reach it in a service. 
If I don't register it in services.yaml, Symfony doesn't find it, it's clear. But if I try to register:

```
Doctrine\:
    resource: '../vendor/doctrine/mongodb-odm/lib/Doctrine/*'
```

it returns an error as well:
(1/1) FatalErrorException
Compile Error: Cannot use 'Bool' as class name as it is reserved
in Bool.php (line 26)

It seems to be uncompatible with php 7 what is however required by Symfony 4.

Does anyone have idea how to solve this contradiction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, which may be useful for others: 
The problem doesn't occur with dev-master / 3.5.x-dev version of doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle. 
https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle#dev-master
Originally composer.json required "^3.0" so composer downloaded 3.4.1 which was the latest stable version. Modifying version to "3.5.x-dev" solved the problem at least for developing.

Answer (score 0):

you can inject the ManagerRegistry and fetch the manager from it

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\ManagerRegistry;

class SomeController
{
    public function someAction(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $user = new Object();
        $user->setName("John");

        $dm = $managerRegistry->getManager();

        $dm->persist($user);
        $dm->flush();
       //do something
    }
}
```